# Aplicações silenciosas

Tags: android, android-eclipse, android-permission

Algumas aplicações ou boa parte delas tem uma opção de instalação "não assistida" ou silenciosa, conhecido como *silent install*, que é fazer a instalação de uma aplicação sem que o usuário ou equipe de suporte precise interagir com essa aplicação em sua instalação.

Comecei a trabalhar numa aplicação terceira, no qual possui a seguinte permissão relacionada:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

Por padrão o **Eclipse** emite o seguinte erro:

```
Permission is only granted to system apps.
```

O que deve ser considerado na hora da criação de uma aplicação silenciosa para Android fora do **Google Play Store**? Porque acontece esse tipo de erro?

Comment: Pela mensagem, parece que só funcionará se o app tiver permissões de root no sistema, o que pra grande parte dos usuários não ocorrerá. Em alguns apps que necessitam disso, geralmente eles emitem um alerta orientando a gente mesmo a "permitir fontes desconhecidas", e depois fazer a instalação.

Comment: @diegofm obrigado pelo comentário. Me esclareceu algumas coisas que ainda não tinha entendido.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O erro informa que essa permissão só pode ser obtida por aplicações do sistema.

Para isso a aplicação terá de existir na *"Android ROM"* e ser assinada com a mesma *key*, ou então, num *rooted device* instalada em `/system/app`(`/system/priv-app` API4.4+)<sup>[fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24296286/2556111)</sup>

Para que o Eclipse deixe de emitir esse erro siga os seguintes passos<sup>[fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13802178/2556111)</sup>:

> Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Lint Error Checking

Procure por `ID = ProtectedPermission` na lista e defina ***Severity*** para algo que não *error*

Se o que pretende é instalar a aplicação fora da **Google Play Store**, não necessita da permissão `android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES`, basta o dispositivo, onde vai ser instalada, ser configurado para "permitir fontes desconhecidas".

A permissão `android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES` é necessária para aplicações que façam a instalação de outras aplicações.

Comment: Como fazer com que **não apareça** o erro eu já tinha pesquisado e entendido. A questão era saber o porque do erro. Eu pesquisei para entender um pouco mais e consegui compreender porque e como exatamente é usado.

Comment: E esse porquê não é o que está nos 2 primeiros parágrafos da resposta?

Comment: Bom, dei uma atenção na resposta do @diegofm publicada como comentário da pergunta e fui um pouco a fundo. Realmente se a aplicação não tiver a "permissão fontes desconhecidas" e sucessivamente eu não inserir `android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES` no `manifest.xml`, a aplicação não será instalada. Para que o _app_, usando _silent install_ ,  funcione corretamente, é necessário ignorar o "erro" fazendo exatamente o que você disse a partir do terceiro parágrafo da sua resposta, que é o que eu já faço atualmente.

Comment: Eu só queria entender um pouco o conceito do [INSTALL_PACKAGES](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INSTALL_PACKAGES)

Comment: Não entendi. Você está a dizer que consegue instalar essa aplicação num dispositivo que não seja *rooted* e que usa ela para instalar outras apps?

Comment: Estou a dizer que não precisa estar _rooted_ para instalar uma aplicação que não esteja no Google Play, basta usar `android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES` . Estou certo?!

Comment: Não, se é só para isso não necessita da permissão `android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES`, basta que seja indicado no dispositivo para "permitir fontes desconhecidas"

Comment: Enfim, agora estou mais esclarecido sobre o assunto. Abraços. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

1. No Eclipse:

   Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Lint Error Checking.

Na lista encontre uma entrada com o id **Permissão protegido**. Defina a gravidade para algo mais recente do que erro. Desta forma, você ainda pode compilar o projeto usando Eclipse.

2. No Android Studio

   File -> Settings -> Editor -> Inspections

Abaixo da opção **Android Lint**, localize **Using system app permission**. Desmarque a caixa de seleção ou escolha uma gravidade menor do que esse erro.

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13802178/6362228